# Elm shorthand to supply type variables to a Union Type

Tags: elm

I have an Elm type like this

```
type ValueAndContext valueType contextType
    = ValueAndContext valueType contextType
```

I would like to create a new type, with the specific type parameters, to save keyboard taps and screen pixels, maybe like this

```
type IntWithStringContext = ValueAndContext Int String
```

I could create a type alias like this, but it requires me to introduce an extra variable to hold the type, so doesn't save that many taps or pixels.

```
type alias IntWithStringContext =
  { update: ValueAndContext Int String }
```

I don't think anything else is possible in Elm, but any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you were pretty close with your first example. You can use an alias like this:

```
type alias IntWithStringContext = ValueAndContext Int String
```

Perhaps it is more common to see type aliases for record types, but you can also alias union types.

**Edit**

This will alias the type name but you still have to use the original constructor:

```
get : IntWithStringContext
get = ValueAndContext 1 "hello"
```

Comment: That does compile, but I can't use it in any useful way. Both of the following cause type errors (I can't add newlines to the comments so you have to infer where they are, sorry)

Comment: get : IntWithStringContext  
get =
    IntWithStringContext  1 "hello"

Comment: get : IntWithStringContext  
get =
    ValueAndContext  1 "hello"

Comment: I provided an example that shows how to use it. [Here it is on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/dVSkWNGdha1/0)

Comment: Thanks Chad. I take it back, that second example of mine does actually work.